# Why does Square(int.MaxValue) return 1?

Tags: c#, behavior

My apologies if this question already exists, but I have not found it here on SO. That's why I ask it. Anyway...

Say you have following very simple method:

```
public int Square(int i)
{
    return i * i;
}
```

When I use the method like this:

```
int result = Square(Int32.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
```

This is the result:

> Result: 1

Why does this compile *and* execute succesfully, and why is 1 returned?

Comment: @wudzik did not see that, sorry! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles, but it runs to completion only in an `unchecked` context, which is the compiler default. Adding a [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) block (or specifying the `/checked` compiler option) will give you an overflow exception at runtime.

If in an unchecked context, the result is `1` because the multiplication goes like this:

```
            0x ffff ffff
*           0x ffff ffff
= 0x ffff fffe 0000 0001
```

The high-order [bits that overflow are discarded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), leaving you with `0x 0000 0001`.

Answer (score 3):

That's a simple overflow of integer value. By default overflow checking is disabled, but if you'll add [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) block, then you'll see exception:

```
public int Square(int i)
{
    checked
    {
        return i * i;
    }
}
```

Why it's compiled? Because compiler can't check if overflow will occur. It can do that with compile-time constants:

```
int result = Int32.MaxValue * Int32.MaxValue;
```

But it can't invoke methods during compilation.

Answer (score 3):

This is because an `int` can not take a larger value than `Int32.MaxValue`. `Int32.MaxValue * Int32.MaxValue` is much lager than `Int32.MaxValue`, so the `int` variable will overflow.

You will notice a similar thing with `int i = Int32.MaxValue + 1`.